# defining the stopping time sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, stopping-times

**For a stopping time T, define $\mathcal{F}_T$ by**

**$\mathcal{F}_T={A \in \mathcal{F}:A \cap \{T \le t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t, \text{for each t.}}$**

**Verify that $\mathcal{F}_T$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.**

To prove this I know we must show that $\mathcal{F}_T$ satisfies the three properties of  $\sigma$-algebras, ie that

A $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of a set X is a collection $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets satisfying the following properties;
(1) $\emptyset$ $\in$ $\mathcal{F}$
(2) if A $\in$ $\mathcal{F}$ then it's compliment $A^{c}$ is also in $\mathcal{F}$
(3) if $A_1,A_2,...$ is a countable collection of sets in $\mathcal{F}$  then their union $\cup^{\infty}_{n=1}A_n \in \mathcal{F}$

I have attempted this myself but am concerned I am not being precise enough. Any hints or comments are gladly welcome.

For (3):
Suppose $A_1,A_2,...$ is a countable collection of sets in $\mathcal{F}_T$
Then $A_n \in \mathcal{F}$ : $A_n \cap \{T \le t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$ for all n by definition
Then $\cup^{\infty}_{n=1}(A_n \cap \{T \le t\})\in \mathcal{F}_t$
Then $(\cup^{\infty}_{n=1}A_n) \cap (\{T \le t\})\in \mathcal{F}_t$ 
Then $(\cup^{\infty}_{n=1}A_n) \in \mathcal{F}_T$

For(2) I am less convinced
My reasoning would be that if $A \in \mathcal{F}_T$ then $A \in \mathcal{F}: A \cap \{T \le t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$
We know that $A \cap \{T \le t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$
Now $A^c \in \mathcal{F}$ since $A^c = \mathcal{F}/A$
Then $A^{c} \cap \{T \le t\} = \mathcal{F} \cap \{T \le t\} - A \cap \{T \le t\}$
Since $\mathcal{F} \cap \{T \le t\} = \mathcal{F}_t$
Then $A^{c} \cap \{T \le t\} = \mathcal{F}_t - A \cap \{T \le t\}$
ie $A^{c} \in \mathcal{F}_T$
However for this to hold we must consider the situation where $A \cap \{T \le t\} = \mathcal{F}_t$
In other words here $A^c$ would be $\emptyset$ and this is where I'm stuck.

If I could prove $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}_T$ (2) would follow so any hints to get me started would be really appreciated as I really don't know where to start, or if I am completely wrong that would also be good to know! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to *refer* to $\mathcal F_T$ in your *definition* of $\mathcal F_T$. That makes it unclear to me.

Comment: Yes I thought that strange as well when reading the problem for the first time but it is the standard definition for this type of filtration with stopping time T

Comment: No, it should read $A \cap \{T \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$.

Comment: You're both completely correct, my apologies, it's a typo on my problem sheet and I didn't notice the subtle difference when checking the definition online, stay with me while i check if any of my work still makes sense or if it's just utter nonsense.

Comment: As far as i can tell it hasn't change my reasoning, but obviously my reasoning could be flawed from the beginning so feel free to tell me where I'm going wrong! Thank you both very much for the correction though, I never would have spotted it!

Comment: Could you add the definition of $\mathcal F_t$ for a fixed $t$?

Comment: I recently answered a similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2065698/397540): maybe this is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{multline}
1) \emptyset : \emptyset \cap \{T\leq n\} =\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}_n \Rightarrow \emptyset \in \mathcal{F}_n
\end{multline}

\begin{multline}
2) \Omega : \Omega \cap \{T\leq n\} =\{T\leq n\} \in \mathcal{F}_n \Rightarrow \Omega \in \mathcal{F}_n
\end{multline}

\begin{multline}
3) A \in \mathcal{F}_n : A \cap \{T\leq n\} \in \mathcal{F}_n \forall n
\end{multline}

We have to prove that $A^c \cap \{T\leq n\}\in \mathcal{F}_n$
\begin{multline}
4) A^c \cap \{T\leq n\} = \underbrace{(A^c \cap \{T\leq n\})^c}_{\in \mathcal{F}_n} \cap \underbrace{\{T\leq n\}}_{\in \mathcal{F}_n}\in \mathcal{F}_n
\end{multline}

\begin{multline}
5) A_k \in \mathcal{F}:(\bigcup^{\infty}_{k=1}A_k) \cap \{T\leq n\} = \bigcup^{\infty}_{k=1} \underbrace{(A_k \cap \{T\leq n\})}_{\in \mathcal{F}_n}\in \mathcal{F}_n
\end{multline}

Comment: It's a bit late, but there's a typo in (4).  On the right-hand side of the equality, it should be A instead of A complement.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument for (2) doesn't make sense - in particular, the statement $A^c=\mathcal{F}-A$ is not defined: On the lefthand side is a set; on the righthand side is a collection of sets.

Start with $A^c=\Omega-A$ (if $\Omega$ is the set on which the filtration is taken), and note $A=(A\cap\{T\le t\})\cup(A^c\cap \{T\le t\})$.