# Question about Markov moment and $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, markov-process

Let $\tau$ be the  Markov moment with respect to the stream $(\mathcal{F}_{t}, t \in T)$. Prove that 
$$
\mathcal{F}_{\tau}=\{A \in \mathcal{F}:  A \cap \{ \tau \leq t \} \in \mathcal{F}_t, \quad \forall t \in T \setminus \{ \infty\} \} 
$$

is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Seems I have to check all axioms for $\sigma$-algebra? But  how to use the Markov moment?

Comment: What is a Markov moment....? Is this a synonym for "stopping time"?

Comment: yes,  it is "stopping time"

Comment: I see. Well... yes, you have to check all axioms. Why not simply give it a try? You will see where you need that $\tau$ is a stopping time as soon as you start proving the assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of a Markov moment or stopping time is a random variable $\tau: \Omega \rightarrow T \subseteq [0,\infty]$ such that 
$$
\{\tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t, \quad t \in T.
$$
In order to show that $\mathcal F_\tau $ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we have to show three properties.

- First, we have to show that $\Omega \in \mathcal F_\tau$. This is simple since for all $t \in T$: 
  $$\Omega\cap \{\tau \leq t\} = \{\tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal F_t,$$ 
  hence $\Omega \in \mathcal F_\tau$.
- Second we have to show that $A \in \mathcal F_\tau $ implies that $A^c$ is also in $\mathcal F_\tau$. So let $A \in \mathcal F_\tau$.  We have to show that $A^c \cap \{\tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal F_t$. Observe that
  $$
   A^c \cap \{\tau \leq t\}=   \underbrace{\{\tau \leq t\}}_{\in \mathcal F_t} \setminus \underbrace{\Bigl(A \cap \{\tau \leq t\} \Bigr)}_{\in \mathcal F_t} \in \mathcal{F}_t,
  $$
  hence $A^c \in \mathcal{F}_\tau$.
- Finally, we have to show that if a countable family $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ lies in $\mathcal F_\tau$ then also have that $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \in \mathcal F_\tau$. So assume $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ is in $\mathcal{F}_\tau$. Then for all $ t \in T$:
  $$
  \Bigl(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \Bigr) \cap \{\tau \leq t\} = \bigcup_{i \in I}\Bigl(\underbrace{A_i \cap \{\tau \leq t\}}_{\in \mathcal{F}_t} \Bigr)  \in \mathcal{F}_t,
  $$
  since $\mathcal F_t$ is a $\sigma$-algebra..