# Theorem 5.2.7 ( Reflection Principle ) (Durrett : Probability Theory and Example )

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, proof-explanation

> **Theorem 5.2.7**
> Let $ξ_1,ξ_2,...$ be independent and identically distributed with a distribution that is symmetric about zero.Let $Sn=ξ_1+···+ξ_n$. If $a >0$ then $P(\sup_{m≤n}S_m≥a)≤2P(S_n≥a)$

In the proof, $N$ is defined as below

$$N= \inf\{m≤n:S_m> a\}\;\;(\text{ with }  \inf\, \emptyset=\infty)$$

and the fact that $\{N\leq n \}\in \mathcal{F}_N$ is used in the proof of the theorem. However, is this fact true?

I thought $\mathcal{F}_N$ is defined when $N$ is fixed. So the reverse should be true. I can't get the concept of $\mathcal{F}_N$ and $\{N\leq n\}$.

Comment: [Q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710585/defining-the-stopping-time-sigma-algebra), [Q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2445077/intuition-regarding-the-sigma-algebra-of-the-past-stopping-times)...

Comment: usually $\mathcal{F}_N$ is defined as the $\sigma $-algebra of a stopping time (namely $N$). In the definition of a stopping time $N$ it is assumed that any set of the form $\{N\leqslant n\}$ is $N$-measurable, i.e., belongs to $\mathcal{F}_N$

Comment: Ok thanks very much !I think I grasped it